# How to find Contour based on specific color outline or border?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, machine-learning, contour

I'm trying to detect count of contour based on yellow color outline showing below in AutoCAD drawing.
[image: snippet]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/htc/Desktop/capture.png')
original = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 208, 94], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([179, 255, 232], dtype="uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Extract contours depending on OpenCV version
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate through contours and filter by the number of vertices 
for c in cnts:
   perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * perimeter, True)
   if len(approx) > 5:
       cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The output i'm expecting to detect these two outline circles(contours) but not achieved. Any one help me in this where i'm doing wrong.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow color has different hue value from the rest. You can use first channel (hue), with value range is `10:15`

```
lower = np.array([10, 0, 0], dtype="uint8") 
upper = np.array([15, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
```

The hue channel indicates the "color" of the image [see this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/184281/how-are-hsv-values-interpreted-in-python/). You can imshow the hue channel

```py
hue = image[:,:,0]
cv2.imshow('hue', hue)
```

It's almost black. Let's "rescale" its value:

```py
cv2.imshow('hue', (hue-np.min(hue))/(np.max(hue)-np.min(hue))*255)
```

[image]
After using MS Paint to find the range of "white zone", I see it is `170-255`, and `np.max(hue) = 15, np.min(hue) = 0`, so the original range is `10-15`.

That's how I got the numbers in `lower` and `upper`. Since you only care about the color, other channel is set to `0,0` for `lower`, and `255,255` for `upper`

Comment: Thanls for your reply! its working in yellow perfectly but can you show me document link where i find all color arrays

Comment: @ShahnawazIrfan I edited my answer, hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your upper boundary cannot detect the color of the circles.
Try setting it to something like this:

```
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
```

Feel free to play around with boundaries more to select your color.